# Android NDK and SYSROOT in Environment

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-ndk

I working with a library that is not `SYSROOT` aware. I've tried fiddling with some of its flags and scripts, but I have not had much luck. The library ignores the user's `CFLAGS`, and I don't read/write `PERL` well.

I've tried exporting `SYSROOT`, `ANDROID_SYSROOT`, and `ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT` with no joy. I've also looked at some similar SO questions/answers, but they apply more to GCC and less to Android and the NDK.

Is there a way to set `SYSROOT` in the environment so I don't have to try and hack this library?

Comment: If it doesn't ignore `CC` you can call it like `CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc make`. If it works at the beginning and fails at later commands do the same for them as well.

Comment: Thanks auselen. Yes, it honors CC. However, the library does not honor `CFLAGS`, so I can't easily add `--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT`. That means Android headers (like `stdio.h`) are missing, and Android libraries (such as `glibc`) are missing. Hence the reason I want the cross compiler to pick it up from the environment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said try with including SYSROOT in CC.